# Random String array return

Tags: java, arrays, string, random

I tried to create a code that outputs a random question. However, constantly I get the error 'Incompatible types: Int cannot be converted to Question'. I understand the error, but I could not get the solution to it for this case. I am new to this, so it might be I just couldn't translate the given answers to my own example. The error is in the lines:

```
        questions[i]=temp;
        temp = questions[index];
```

This snippet can be found in the following code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Welcome to the geography quiz");
    System.out.println("Press a key to begin");            
    String start = keyboardInput.nextLine();

    String q1 = "What is the capital of Belgium?";
    String q2 = "\nWhat is the capital of Chile?";
    String q3 = "\nWhat is the capital of the Netherlands?";

    Question[]questions={
        new Question(q1, "Brussels", "No alternative"),
        new Question(q2, "Santiago de Chile", "Santiago"),
        new Question(q3, "Amsterdam", "No alternative")
    };

    takeTest(questions);
}

public static void takeTest(Question[]questions){
    int score = 0;
    int index, temp;
    Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    Random rnd = new Random();
    for(int i= questions.length -1; i>0; i--){
        index = rnd.nextInt(i+1);
        questions[index] = questions[i];
        questions[i]=temp;
        temp = questions[index];

        System.out.println(questions[i].prompt);
        String a = keyboardInput.nextLine();          

        if (a.equalsIgnoreCase(questions[i].answer)) {
            score++;
        }else if(a.equalsIgnoreCase(questions[i].alternative)){
            score++;
        }
    } 
    System.out.println("You got " + score + " out of " + questions.length);
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Isn't this error clear enough to understand? You just assigned an `int` to a `Question` type.

Comment: Sweet! I can get a 66% by just answering "No alternative"!

Comment: @Elliott Frisch That is the next part of my investigation. How to get rid of that part. But to make it work, I had to put it for now. Thanks for the heads up..

Comment: @Jai Ofcourse I understand the error, I just do not know how to get rid of the error since my input will always be a String value, where the solutions I found on this webpage always get me into this error.

Comment: Use a list if it is allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that you want the **temp** is Question type? Try the code below if it helps.

```
public static void takeTest(Question[]questions){
    int score = 0;
    int index;
    Question temp;
    Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    Random rnd = new Random();
    for(int i= questions.length -1; i>0; i--){
        index = rnd.nextInt(i+1);
        questions[index] = questions[i];
        questions[i]=temp;
        temp = questions[index];

        System.out.println(questions[i].prompt);
        String a = keyboardInput.nextLine();          

        if (a.equalsIgnoreCase(questions[i].answer)) {
            score++;
        }else if(a.equalsIgnoreCase(questions[i].alternative)){
            score++;
        }
    } 
    System.out.println("You got " + score + " out of " + questions.length);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your correction! I tried it, and it seems to work, though I now need to find out how to initialize the value. Learning to code is getting from one problem into the other!

Answer (score 1):

In your code you declare the variable named `temp` as an `int` (i.e. `int index, temp;`). Later, you attempt to assign `questions[i]` the value of `temp`. But `questions[i]` is of type `Question` while `temp` is of type `int`. Since they have different types, you can't assign on to the other. You probably want to make `temp` have type `Question` instead of `int`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Appearantly I was close than, since I first changed it to String, but it didn't work.. Now let me find how to initialize this value..